# Set environment parameter in Nix for a building phase for buildGoModule?

Tags: nix

I am trying to build a Go moodule with `buildGoModule`. My issue is that during building time `go` tries to reach out to *proxy.golang.org* but it is block in my network and solution is to set an environment variable `GOPROXY`.

I thought that `passthru = { GOPROXY = "direct"; };` would do the job, but the error persists. So I would like to know what is a good way to pass an env variable.

Overriding `GOPROXY` should work since I tested it in `nix-shell` separately - it works fine.

Comment: `passthru` only sets attributes on the Nix level and does not pass the values to the builder.  https://nixos.org/nixpkgs/manual/#ssec-stdenv-attributes You'll have to set it directly on all derivations that fetch go _sources_. This seems to be undocumented.

Comment: Yep overriding `GOPROXY` in `overrideModAttrs` makes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [`buildGoModule`](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/pkgs/development/go-modules/generic/default.nix) it is possible to override go-modules derivation with [`overrideModAttrs`](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/pkgs/development/go-modules/generic/default.nix#L11).

Specifically for `GOPROXY` it would look like:

```
overrideModAttrs = (_: {
  GOPROXY = "whatever";
});
```